# C# Bind Generic List To Textbox WinForms?

Tags: c#, data-binding, list, textbox

I have a method that returns a list of type string. I want to bind each item in the list to the textbox so essentially it looks like a listbox, except it will be editable since its actually a textbox!

any ideas on how to go about doing this!?

CODE:

```
public List<string> GetAgentsDetails(string writeDir)
    {
        List<string> agentInfoList = new List<string>();

        XElement doc = XElement.Load(writeDir);

        var getDetails =
            (from n in doc.Elements("Agent")
             select n.Element("Name").Value + "," + n.Element("EmailAddress").Value);
        foreach (var info in getDetails)
        {
            agentInfoList.Add(info);
        }
        return agentInfoList;

    }
```

Comment: what type of binding do you want to use? one way, data -> control, or two-way, date <-> control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the top of my head:

```
MyTextBox.Lines = GetAgentsDetails(writeDir).ToArray();
```

Ofcourse your TextBox should be multiline.

Comment: Thankyou, i was using tostring instead of toarray.......yesterday was a long day, it seems!